# Maximise the volume of an open triangular prism

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

An open container is to be constructed out of 200 square centimeters of cardboard. The two end pieces are equilateral triangles. The open top is a horizontal rectangle. Find the lengths of the sides of the triangle for maximum volume of the container.

So effectively we have an equilateral triangular prism of length $L$.

I first found an equation for $L$:  $$L=\frac{200-\sqrt{3}x^2}{2x}$$

I then used $V = \frac{1}{2}x^2Lsin60$ to get the volume, substituting for $L$ to get the volume in terms of $x$.

Differentiating with respect to $x$, setting equal to zero, and solving for $x$ gave me value of $x=6.2$

$$\frac{dv}{dx} = 50\sqrt{0.75} - \frac{9x^2}{8} = 0$$
x=6.204

But this answer was marked wrong by my teacher. Where had I gone wrong?

Comment: I think you should latex your question.

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: What is meant by an open container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression for the area of the shape will be:$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x^2+2Lx=200$$And the volume will be :$$V=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x^2L$$
From the first equation, $$L=\frac{400-\sqrt{3}x^2}{4x}$$
Putting it in the volume equation gives:$$V=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}(400x-\sqrt3x^3)$$
So $$\frac{dV}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}(400-3\sqrt3x^2)$$
Setting this to zero gives the value of $x=8.7738, L=7.5983$ and $ V=253.27$

Comment: Thank you. I now see I went wrong in rearranging the original expression for L, forgetting about the fraction on the x^2 term.

Answer (score 2):

Let's let our variable x represent the side of the equilateral triangle. In that case, the area of the equilateral triangle is $$\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

Therefore, the remaining area for the cardboard to be used by the three rectangles is $$200-
\Big(\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}\Big)2$$ Because we have three sides, the area taken up by a single rectangle will be $$\frac{200-
\Big(\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}\Big)2}{3}$$

Because one of the dimensions of the rectangle is x, we can divide by this to find the length, giving$$\frac{200-
\Big(\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}\Big)2}{3x}$$

The total formula for the volume, therefore, is $$V(x)=\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4} \cdot\frac{200-
\Big(\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}\Big)2}{3x}$$
$$\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4} \cdot\frac{200-
\Big(x^2\sqrt{3}\Big)2}{12x}$$

$$\frac{200x^2\sqrt{3}-
2\Big(x^2\sqrt{3}\Big)^2}{48x}$$

$$\frac{200x^2\sqrt{3}-
6x^4}{48x}$$

$$\frac{100x\sqrt{3}-
3x^3}{24}$$

$$-8x^3+\frac{25\sqrt{3}}{6}x$$

The first derivative is

$$V'(x)=-24x^2+\frac{25\sqrt{3}}{6}$$

The roots of this equation are approximately -0.548 and 0.548. These are the critical points. The second derivative is

$$V''(x)=-48x$$

I will let you try and figure out which one is the minimum and which is the maximum, and what the final answer is.

Comment: there are only two rectangles. the "open top" is one of the rectangular sides, whilst the two ends of the box are triangles

Answer (score 2):

So this is an incorrect answer to your question, and maybe I can shed some light on it.  I assume there are 4 pieces of cardboard.  The two equilateral triangles, and two rectangles are cut out.  The sum of the areas of the 4 pieces is 200 cm^2.  The area of an equilateral triangle with side length x is 
$$ A = (\sqrt3) / 4 * x^2 $$
The total area of the cardboard is 2*rectangle_area + 2*triangle_area.  The total area is 200 cm^2.  So
$$ 200 = 2*L*x + [(\sqrt3)/2]*x^2$$
Solving for L yields
$$ L = 100/x - ((\sqrt3)/4)*x $$
The volume of the prism is the area of the triangle times the length.
$$ V = (\sqrt3)/2 *x^2*L$$
Substituting our expression for L gives
$$ V =  (\sqrt3)/2 *x^2*[100/x - ((\sqrt3)/4)*x]$$
This simplifies to
$$ V = 50(\sqrt3)x - (3/8)x^3$$
so then take derivative with respect to x
$$ dV/dx = 50(\sqrt3) - x^2/8$$
Set derivative equal to 0 and solve for x.
$$x = 20\sqrt(\sqrt3)$$
And finally x= 26.3 cm.
I can plug into the expression for L above and find that L = -7.6, so I must have an error.
[image]

Regards, Matt

Comment: sorry, that was an error by me and that was not used in the actual answer I gave. I have since edited my post